# Postgres Docker container: Run command on startup

Tags: postgresql, shell, docker, dockerfile

I have following Dockerfile to create a Postgres container with a third party app:

```
FROM postgres

COPY ./setup/third-party-app.deb /opt/third-party-app.deb
COPY ./setup/init_extensions-db.sql /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/init_extensions-db.sql

RUN apt-get update -y
RUN apt-get install -y default-jre-headless
RUN dpkg -i /opt/third-party-app.deb
RUN service third-party-app init
RUN service third-party-app start
```

But I noticed that the `service third-party-app start` was successfully executed during the build phase, but than the service was not started in the running container.
I figured the reason is that Docker images don't snapshot the running process.
So I am trying to find a way to automatically execute this command after the container has started.

I tried following code at the end of the Dockerfile:

```
CMD postgres && service third-party-app start
```

But the container exits with error status code 1.

I also tried to copy following shell script into the `docker-entrypoint-initdb.d` of the Postgres image:

```
COPY ./setup/third-party-app-start.sh /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/third-party-app-start.sh
```

third-party-app-start.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e
service third-party-app start
```

But the same happens. The container exits with error status code 1.

But when I execute the command manually via PowerShell after the container has started it works perfectly fine.

Is there a better way to accomplish this?
Or is there a way to get a detailed error log of what went wrong with that command?

Comment: https://github.com/just-containers/s6-overlay

Answer (score 0):

> A container’s main running process is the ENTRYPOINT and/or CMD at the
>   end of the Dockerfile. It is generally recommended that you separate
>   areas of concern by using one service per container. That service may
>   fork into multiple processes (for example, Apache web server starts
>   multiple worker processes). It’s ok to have multiple processes, but to
>   get the most benefit out of Docker, avoid one container being
>   responsible for multiple aspects of your overall application. You can
>   connect multiple containers using user-defined networks and shared
>   volumes.

In order to achieve your goal, you will need to use a wrapper script or supervisor, more details: https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/multi-service_container/

Comment: or split the services into multiple containers

Comment: I tried the wrapper script but the container still crashes on startup with status code 127. And I don't find any startup log in the container to find out what went wrong.